# Как запустить docker-compose

Tags: django, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

Коллеги, запускаю docker-compose up --bild и появляется ошибка:

> failed to solve: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to solve with
> frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to read dockerfile: open
> /var/lib/docker/tmp/buildkit-mount870402920/Dockerfile: no such file
> or directory

Dockerfile и docker-compose лежат в корне проекта.

> dima@DESKTOP-1BLNH42:/mnt/c/shop$ ls
> Dockerfile  account  blog  cart  discount_system  docker-compose.yaml  favorites  loyalty_program  manage.py  orders  projectshop  requirements.txt  search  shop  venv

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.9

RUN apt-get update -y
RUN apt-get upgrade -y

WORKDIR /app

COPY ./requirements.txt ./
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . ./src

CMD ['python3', './src/manage.py', 'runserver', '0.0.0.0:8000']
```

docker-compose:

```
version: '3.9'

services:
  rabbitmq:
    image: rabbitmq
    restart: always

  web:
    restart: always
    build:
      context: ./shop
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    command: ['python3', './src/manage.py', 'runserver', '0.0.0.0:8000']
    depends_on:
      - pg_db

  pg_db:
    image: postgres:14
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/

volumes:
  postgres_data:
```

Comment: sudo перед командой - не помогает?

Comment: Нет, не помогает. Он пишет, что failed to read dockerfile: read /var/lib/docker/tmp/buildkit-mount296913897/shop. Попробовал зайти по пути и в папке lib папки docker вообще нет.

Answer (score 1):

Починил файлик убрав context и переписав build. Заработало

```
version: '3.9'

services:
  rabbitmq:
    image: rabbitmq
    restart: always

  web:
    build: .
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    command: ['python3', './src/manage.py', 'runserver', '0.0.0.0:8000']
    depends_on:
      - pg_db

  pg_db:
    image: postgres:14
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: mypassword

volumes:
  postgres_data:
```

Comment: Круто, что разобрался!